# (SwiftUI change detection) What is wrong with this piece of code?

Tags: swiftui

When debugging an issue with an app I am working on, I managed to shrink it down to this minimal example:

```
class RadioModel: ObservableObject {
    @Published var selected: Int = 0
}
struct RadioButton: View {
    let idx: Int
    @EnvironmentObject var radioModel: RadioModel
    var body: some View {
        Button(action: {
            self.radioModel.selected = self.idx
        }, label: {
            if radioModel.selected == idx {
                Text("Button \(idx)").background(Color.yellow)
            } else {
                Text("Button \(idx)")
            }
        })
    }
}
struct RadioListTest: View {
    @ObservedObject var radioModel = RadioModel()
    var body: some View {
        return VStack {
            Text("You selected: \(radioModel.selected)")
            RadioButton(idx: 0)
            RadioButton(idx: 1)
            RadioButton(idx: 2)
        }.environmentObject(radioModel)
    }
}
struct ContentView: View {
    @State var refreshDate = Date()
    func refresh() {
        print("Refreshing...")
        self.refreshDate = Date()
    }
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            Text("\(refreshDate)")
            HStack {
                Button(action: {
                    self.refresh()
                }, label: {
                    Text("Refresh")
                })
                RadioListTest()
            }
        }
    }
}
```

This code looks pretty reasonable to me, although it exhibit a peculiar bug: when I hit the `Refresh` button, the radio buttons stop working. The radio buttons are not refreshed, and keep a reference to the old `RadioModel` instance, so when I click them they update that, and not the new one created after `Refresh` causes a new `RadioListTest` to be constructed. I suspect there is something wrong in the way I use `EnvironmentObject`s but I didn't find any reference suggesting that what I am doing is wrong. I know I could fix this particular problem in various ways that force a refresh in the radio buttons, but I would like to be able to understand which cases require a refresh forcing hack, I can't sprinkle the code with these just because "better safe than sorry", the performance is going to be hell if I have to redraw everything every time I make a modification.

edit: a clarification. The thing that is weird in my opinion and for which I would want an explanation, is this: why on `refresh` the `RadioListTest` is re-created (together with a new `RadioModel`) and its `body` re-evaluated but `RadioButton`s are created and the `body` properties are not evaluated, but the previous `body` is used. They both have only a view model as state, the same view model actually, but one have it as `ObservedObject` and the other as `EnvironmentObject`. I suspect it is a misuse of `EnvironmentObject` that I am doing, but I can't find any reference to why it is wrong

Comment: can you please check your code again please? it is not compilable....error: Generic parameter 'Content' could not be inferred

Comment: @Chris yeh sorry the parameter has to be removed, it isn't used anymore

Answer (score 0):

this works: (yes, i know, you know how to solve it, but i think this would be the "right" way.

problem is this line:

```
struct RadioListTest: View {
    @ObservedObject var radioModel = RadioModel(). <<< problem
```

because the radioModel will be newly created each time the RadioListTest view is refreshed, so just create the instance one view above and it won't be created on every refresh (or do you want it to be created every time?!)

```
class RadioModel: ObservableObject {
    @Published var selected: Int = 0

    init() {
        print("init radiomodel")
    }
}
struct RadioButton<Content: View>: View {
    let idx: Int
    @EnvironmentObject var radioModel: RadioModel
    var body: some View {
        Button(action: {
            self.radioModel.selected = self.idx
        }, label: {
            if radioModel.selected == idx {
                Text("Button \(idx)").background(Color.yellow)
            } else {
                Text("Button \(idx)")
            }
        })
    }
}
struct RadioListTest: View {
    @EnvironmentObject var radioModel: RadioModel

    var body: some View {
        return VStack {
            Text("You selected: \(radioModel.selected)")
            RadioButton<Text>(idx: 0)
            RadioButton<Text>(idx: 1)
            RadioButton<Text>(idx: 2)
        }.environmentObject(radioModel)
    }
}
struct ContentView: View {
    @ObservedObject var radioModel = RadioModel()

    @State var refreshDate = Date()
    func refresh() {
        print("Refreshing...")
        self.refreshDate = Date()
    }
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            Text("\(refreshDate)")
            HStack {
                Button(action: {
                    self.refresh()
                }, label: {
                    Text("Refresh")
                })
                RadioListTest().environmentObject(radioModel)

            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: yeh if all the state is global and singleton there is no problem with double instances. But that doesn't scale for a bigger application. If there is a complex application with navigation and potentially a large number of `RadioLists`, I can't initialize everything in the root view and then pass it down, I need to be able to incapsulate subviews state.

Comment: Think for example of representing a filesystem navigation, and each radio button is a directory you can select to navigate into (kind of like MacOS "Open File" dialog).

Comment: i have understood this with your first comment already ;) i am thinking of another solutions...but this is not the "first question" anymore...it is a second one ;)

Comment: to be clear: It is OK for the model to be re-created (and its status reset) every time the parent changes, that's not the issue I'm investigating. I would expect the button's `body` to be re-evaluated when I change the `EnvironmentObject` instance associated with it (which happens when `refreshDate` changes), but it doesn't

Comment: the question was never "how I can make this work", but "what am I doing wrong".

Answer (score 0):

> What is wrong with this piece of code?

Your `RadioListTest` subview is not updated on `refresh()` because it does not depend on changed parameter (`refreshDate` in this case), so SwiftUI rendering engine assume it is equal to previously created and does nothing with it:

```
HStack {
    Button(action: {
        self.refresh()
    }, label: {
        Text("Refresh")
    })
    RadioListTest()     // << here !!
}
```

so the solution is to make this view dependent somehow on changed parameter, if it is required of course, and here fixed variant

```
RadioListTest().id(refreshDate)
```

Comment: `RadioListTest` is updated and its `body` called every time the parent view is refreshed. This is also the cause of the two instance of `RadioModel`. You can check that with a breakpoint on methods `init` and `body`. Its subviews are not updated though, and that's what causing the bug.

Comment: somehow not adding explicit `id` makes SwiftUI identify the `RadioButtons` before and after the change as the same - so it doesn't re-evaluate their `body` property even if it re-creates them (because it re-evaluates `RadioListTest` view `body` property that invokes their constructor). So you are suggesting I use `id` to force re-evaluation of all subviews every time a view property change, because otherwise swiftui might decide to only partial re-evaluate them (and create inconsistent state)?

Comment: @pqnet, subviews are not refreshed for the same reason - equality. It is core concept of SwiftUI - don't refresh view if it it is equal to previously constructed (views are just values, so compared as regular structs). Anyway it is up to you how to fix it.

Comment: But they technically aren't equal. They have a different `radioModel` reference. Is it a bug in `EnvironmentObject`?

Comment: @pqnet, no - environment object is not part of view, technically. ))

Comment: That's strange, because the view is redrawn if I modify the environment object properties, but not if I change the environment object instance (and reset all its properties to the default value). Note that on `refresh` the `You selected: \(radioModel.selected)` is reset to zero, while the highlighted view stays the one you clicked last before `refresh`.